# Why do I need reputation for each individual SE site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I have a feeling this will be closed, but please hear me out. Why do I need reputation for each site to perform basic functions like comment and vote; where I can do this on 2 of the 5 sites I frequent alas I cannot perform these on all of my most frequented SE sites. This seems silly as some sites seem very closely related. Why isn't there a feature where if you have X amount of rep on let's say a few sites, you can extend your rep to another site? I feel at a certain point the constraints are unnecessary for what I would consider frequent and intelligent users. If this is already put in to place how can I obtain this?

Thanks for listening!

Comment: Get 200 on one and you're all good.

Comment: The association bonus is described in the last bullet under "You gain reputation when" in the duplicate.

Comment: Ok thank you for all the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are requesting is called an *account association* bonus, and has already been implemented.

Enjoy!

> At new user login time, in addition to association, we also:
>
> 1. **Grant you a +100 reputation bonus on the current site,** as long as you have at least +200 reputation on any site in our network. So you’re not treated like a newbie on every new site we launch.
> 2. … etc.

*Source: [New Automatic Account Association](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/)*

Answer (score 1):

*Some* sites are closely related. Many others aren't even *remotely* related.

An across-the-board rep transfer is unreasonable; my SO rep should be useless (or actively count against me!) on [English](http://english.stackexchange.com), for example. As mentioned, *some* privilege is automatically granted, but anything beyond that strikes me as unwise: earn your reputation everywhere, I say.